# How to create a dynamic back button?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6, angular7, ionic4

I am currently working on an application in ionic4, I have a restaurant detail page which can be reached by two ways. 1 by click on a restaurant card in the home page and the 2nd is clicking on a google map marker.

So as you guess in the first case I would like to return to the Homepage and in the 2nd case I want to return to my map.

this is my map.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="markerClicked" class="restaurant-info-overlay">
    <mm-list-card [restaurant]="restaurant"></mm-list-card>

    <ion-row class="s-margin-b">
        <ion-col class="s-padding-r" size="6" no-padding>
            <mm-navigation-button [destination]="[51.568928, 4.618768]" 
                [shape]="'round'" [color]="'white'" [expand]="'full'" 
                [icon]="true"></mm-navigation-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="s-padding-l" size="6" no-padding>
            <ion-button shape="round" color="primary" expand="full"
                [routerLink]="'/restaurant/' + restaurant._id"  routerDirection="forward" detail="true">
                book table
            </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</div>

<!--create a element for map. #Map - identifier -->
<div #Map class="map"></div>
```

and this is the routerLink in the slide-card.component

```
    [routerLink]="'/restaurant/' + restaurant.Restaurant._id" routerDirection="forward" detail="true">
```

What could I do to achieve a dynamic back button. I had a thought of setting a parentView, and do something like this:

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
    {{ parentView }}
  <ion-back-button [attr.defaultHref]="parentView === 'home' ? '/' : '/test'"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Could somebody help me out on this?

the app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'restaurant/:id', loadChildren: './pages/detail/detail.module#DetailPageModule' },
  { path: 'aanbiedingen', loadChildren: './pages/offers/offers.module#OffersPageModule' },
  { path: 'saved', loadChildren: './pages/saved/saved.module#SavedPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and the tab.routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        children: [{ path: '', loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule' }]
      },
      {
        path: 'reserveringen',
        children: [{ path: '', loadChildren: '../reservations/reservations.module#ReservationPageModule' }]
      },
      {
        path: 'zoeken',
        children: [
          { path: 'type/:id', loadChildren: '../search/search.module#SearchPageModule' },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'opgeslagen',
        children: [{ path: '', loadChildren: '../saved/saved.module#SavedPageModule' }]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I implemented a service that solves the same issue on my side and it might be handy for other people as well. The idea came from this [blog post](https://blog.hackages.io/our-solution-to-get-a-previous-route-with-angular-5-601c16621cf0)

The service allows to save the router navigation history entries and by skipping the last 2 values, we can get the latest navigated route.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingState {
  private history: string[] = [];

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public loadRouting(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
          filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        )
      .subscribe(({urlAfterRedirects}: NavigationEnd) => {
          this.history = [...this.history, urlAfterRedirects];
      },
      error => { throw new Error(error); }
      );
  }    

  /**
   * Gives the previous URL from the navigation history.
   */
  public getPreviousUrl(): string {
    return this.history[this.history.length - 2];
  }
}
```

The `loadRouting()` method can be called from the app.component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(routingState: RoutingState) {
    routingState.loadRouting();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me in Angular, even when you come from external URL.

```
window.history.back()
```